# Python (Excel, dictionary) how to write it shorter

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I wrote a program that is too long and I'm sure that I can write it shorter.

This is a function that export values from Excel:

```
#"place" is a place where I have Excel file "book1.xlsx" 
place=os.path.join(DATA_DIR,'book1.xlsx')
Excel=win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb=Excel.Workbooks.Open(place)
sheet=wb.ActiveSheet

#we are reading information from Excel
# I have a table in Excel. This table has a name "Table'
#TI3_value is a column in Table with name TI3 
#TI3_value is a list, for example, [4.97, 3.02,1.02] 
TI3_value=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[TI3]")]

#TI4_value is a column in Table with name TI4
TI4_value=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[TI4]")]
TI5_value=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[TI5]")]

Frank_value=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[Frank]")]
Shanh_value=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[Shanh]")]
Manil_value=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[Manil]")]

TI3_name=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[TI3_name]")]
TI4_name=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[TI4_name]")]
TI5_name=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[TI4_name]")]

Frank_value=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[Frank_name]")]
Shanh_value=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[Shanh_name]")]
Manil_value=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[Manil_name]")] 

TI3_name=[x for x in TI3_name if str(x)!='None'
```

As you can see, it's not a compact code.

> How can I write it shorter?

---

I tried to use a dictionary....

```
Heroes_name={'TI3_name':1,'TI4_name':2,'TI5_name':3,
             'Frank_name':4,'Shanh_name':5,'Manil_name':6}

for hero in Heroes_name:
    hero=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range('Table[%s]' % hero)]

TI3_name=[x for x in TI3_name if str(x)!='None']
```

But I got the following error:

```
local variable 'TI3_name' referenced before assignment
```

---

**Anyway... how can I write my program shorter?**

**UPDATE:**
Alexey Bogomolov wrote:
"Unfortunately, it is still not clear for me, what are you going to have"

I wrote a program that is too long and I'm sure that I can write it shorter. How can I do that? (it is a complete program code)

```
import os
import win32com.client
import numpy as np

from utils import DATA_DIR
def read_from_excel():
    place=os.path.join(DATA_DIR,'book1.xlsx')
    Excel=win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    wb=Excel.Workbooks.Open(place)
    sheet=wb.ActiveSheet


    TI3_name=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[TI3_Name]")]

    TI4_name=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[TI4_Name]")]
    TI5_name=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[TI5_Name]")]
    Frank_name=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[Frank_name]")]
    Shanh_name=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[Shanh_name]")]
    Manil_name=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[Manil_name]")]

    TI3_value=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[TI3]")]

    TI4_value=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[TI4]")]
    TI5_value=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[TI5]")]

    Frank_value=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[Frank]")]
    Shanh_value=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[Shanh]")]
    Manil_value=[r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("Table[Manil]")]

    TI3_name=[x for x in TI3_name if str(x)!='None']
    TI4_name=[x for x in TI4_name if str(x)!='None']
    TI5_name=[x for x in TI5_name if str(x)!='None']

    Frank_name=[x for x in Frank_name if str(x)!='None']
    Shanh_name=[x for x in Shanh_name if str(x)!='None']
    Manil_name=[x for x in Manil_name if str(x)!='None']

    TI3_value=[x for x in TI3_value if str(x)!='None']
    TI4_value=[x for x in TI4_value if str(x)!='None']
    TI5_value=[x for x in TI5_value if str(x)!='None']

    Frank_value=[x for x in Frank_value if str(x)!='None']
    Shanh_value=[x for x in Shanh_value if str(x)!='None']
    Manil_value=[x for x in Manil_value if str(x)!='None']

    TI3=list(zip(TI3_name,TI3_value))
    TI4=list(zip(TI4_name, TI4_value))
    TI5=list(zip(TI5_name, TI5_value))

    Frank=list(zip(Frank_name, Frank_value))
    Shanh=list(zip(Shanh_name, Shanh_value))
    Manil=list(zip(Manil_name, Manil_value))

    TI3=np.array(TI3)
    TI4=np.array(TI4)
    TI5=np.array(TI5)

    Frank=np.array(Frank)
    Shanh=np.array(Shanh)
    Manil=np.array(Manil)

    return TI3, TI4, TI5, Frank, Shanh, Manil

def find_number_uniq_heroes(TI3, TI4, TI5, Frank, Shanh, Manil):
   x1=TI3[:,0]
   x2=TI4[:,0]
   x3=TI5[:,0]
   x4=Frank[:,0]
   x5=Shanh[:,0]
   x6=Manil[:,0]

   x=np.concatenate((x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6),0)
   y=np.unique(x)


   return y
def number_popular(x,y,hero):
    try:
        i=x.tolist().index(hero)
        return float(y[i])    
    except ValueError:
        return float(0)


def count_popularity(uniq_heroes,TI3, TI4, TI5, Frank, Shanh, Manil):

    n=len(uniq_heroes)
    popul=np.zeros(n)

    x1=TI3[:,0]
    x2=TI4[:,0]
    x3=TI5[:,0]
    x4=Frank[:,0]
    x5=Shanh[:,0]
    x6=Manil[:,0]

    y1=TI3[:,1]
    y2=TI4[:,1]
    y3=TI5[:,1]
    y4=Frank[:,1]
    y5=Shanh[:,1]
    y6=Manil[:,1]


    i=0
    for hero in uniq_heroes:

        pop=float(0)
        pop=number_popular(x1,y1,hero)
        pop=pop+number_popular(x2,y2,hero)
        pop=pop+number_popular(x3,y3,hero)
        pop=pop+number_popular(x4,y4,hero)
        pop=pop+number_popular(x5,y5,hero)
        pop=pop+number_popular(x6,y6,hero)

    popul[i]=float(pop)
    i=i+1


    return list(zip(uniq_heroes,popul))

def sort_mass(x):

    x=sorted(x,key=lambda x_entry:x_entry[1],reverse=True)

    return x


TI3, TI4, TI5, Frank, Shanh, Manil = read_from_excel()
uniq_heroes=find_number_uniq_heroes(TI3, TI4, TI5, Frank, Shanh, Manil)
un_her_with_popul=count_popularity(uniq_heroes,TI3, TI4, TI5, Frank, Shanh, Manil)
sorted_mas=sort_mass(un_her_with_popul)

print(sorted_mas[:10])
```

Comment: The error is obvious, because you're referencing TI3_name during assignment, whoch is not correct.

Comment: Alexey Bogomolov, yes, I know but How can I write my program shorter? I have a lot of names from Excel, for example, TI3_name, TI4_name, etc. Maybe I can determine these variables shorter?

Comment: I mean the dictionary is a super tool and I could write it shorter but this idea does not work with the dictionary. Maybe Python can give me some tools that can help to write this shorter.

Comment: You should also use different variables. For example, in for-loop `hero_values = [val[0].value for val in sheet.Range('Table[{}]'.format(hero)]`. You could also try to use empty list and then fill it with names. Such as `names_list = [] ; names_list.append(name)`. Unfortunately, it is still not clear for me, what are you going to have in result.

Comment: "Unfortunately, it is still not clear for me, what are you going to have in result". I edited my post. You can find full code. I hope this help to see that I want to see in result. I'd like to write my program shorter to develop my program skill. But I don't know how to do that. My program is to work. It's ok. But I'd like to know how to write it shorter.

Comment: Could you please share xls file too? In fact, the program could be much shorter if xls file is converted to csv, and then use csv-parser.

Comment: http://www.fayloobmennik.net/6323424

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/book1_1   this is my file, xls file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I have no Excel installed, I've converted your file to [csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vmcvhc5a5ciiqmv/sheet1.csv?dl=1), and wrote a simple parser, which returns table headers and a dictionary with every header and it's values. I hope, this is a good starting point, since you can do whatever you want with dictionary values)

```
import csv


def return_column(rownubmer, delimiter_value):
    column = {}
    column_values = []   
    file = open('sheet1.csv')
    data = csv.reader(file, delimiter=delimiter_value)
    header = next(data)
    for row in data:
        try:
            column_values.append(row[rownubmer])
        except IndexError:
            pass
    column[header[rownubmer]] = column_values
    return column

n = return_column(0, ',')
m = return_column(1, ',')

print(n,m)
```

The output is:

```
{'TI3_name': ['Batrider', 'Outworld Devourer', 'Lifestealer', 'Visage', 'Chen', 'Io', 'Alchemist', 'Dark Seer', 'Weaver', "Nature's Prophet", 'Dragon Knight', 'Naga Siren', 'Gyrocopter', 'Rubick', 'Nyx Assassin', 'Razor', 'Puck', 'Shadow Demon', 'Enchantress', 'Lone Druid', 'Bane', 'Keeper of the Light', 'Anti-Mage', 'Beastmaster', 'Treant Protector', 'Bounty Hunter', 'Timbersaw', 'Queen of Pain', 'Enigma', 'Storm Spirit', 'Clockwerk', 'Shadow Fiend', 'Vengeful Spirit', 'Jakiro', 'Magnus', 'Crystal Maiden', 'Tinker', 'Spectre', 'Windranger', 'Leshrac', 'Juggernaut', 'Sand King', 'Ursa', 'Doom', 'Chaos Knight', 'Earthshaker', 'Tidehunter', 'Mirana', 'Templar Assassin', 'Venomancer', 'Phantom Lancer', 'Morphling', 'Lina', 'Viper', 'Skywrath Mage', 'Silencer', 'Kunkka', 'Disruptor', 'Pudge', 'Lion', 'Axe', 'Ancient Apparition', 'Faceless Void', 'Luna', 'Lich', 'Clinkz', 'Undying', 'Sven', 'Spirit Breaker', 'Pugna', 'Omniknight', 'Slark', 'Dazzle', 'Meepo', 'Bloodseeker', 'Shadow Shaman', 'Slardar', 'Zeus', 'Wraith King', 'Bristleback', 'Tiny', 'Invoker', 'Broodmother', 'Ogre Magi', 'Night Stalker', 'Warlock', 'Sniper', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']} {'TI3': ['4.97', '4.69', '4.66', '4.63', '4.32', '4.14', '4.07', '4.07', '3.77', '3.4', '3.3', '3.12', '2.9', '2.84', '2.41', '2.31', '2.31', '2.04', '1.98', '1.88', '1.82', '1.54', '1.54', '1.42', '1.42', '1.36', '1.3', '1.2', '1.17', '1.14', '1.11', '1.08', '1.05', '1.05', '0.93', '0.86', '0.86', '0.74', '0.68', '0.68', '0.62', '0.62', '0.59', '0.56', '0.52', '0.49', '0.46', '0.46', '0.43', '0.37', '0.37', '0.37', '0.34', '0.28', '0.22', '0.19', '0.15', '0.15', '0.15', '0.12', '0.12', '0.12', '0.12', '0.12', '0.12', '0.09', '0.09', '0.09', '0.06', '0.06', '0.06', '0.06', '0.06', '0.06', '0.06', '0.06', '0.06', '0.03', '0.03', '0.03', '0.03', '0.03', '0.03', '0.03', '0.03', '0.03', '0.03', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']}
```

In case you encounter IndexError exception, you can change the for-loop to something like:

```
for row in data:
    try:
        lis.append(row[rownubmer])
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

But actually the script should just work...

Comment: Error in return_dic                                                                      lis.append(row[rownumber])                                                         IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: That's strange. Please check if csv-file is in the same directory as python file. I also edited parser to handle several columns. This should work.

Comment: the same error:  
Error in return_dic lis.append(row[rownumber]) IndexError: list index out of range   Your parser can read file. Your parser can see csv file. It's ok for a lot of columns but later I see this error.

Comment: The same error. I will send you my program and csv file. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/6_1  You can find here your_parser.py, book.csv and book.xlsx . I have the table in book.xlsx. And I opened Excel 2010 and saved book.xlsx to book.csv.

Comment: Of course! I thought, you're using my file I have added in my first answer. The csv-file you've provided has `;` delimiter, mine has default `,` delimiter. You can either export csv with correct delimiter or specify it in line 7: `data=csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')`

Comment: Alexey Bogomolov, thank you very much for your time and for your explanation. It works. Now I know that I can export csv file and I know how to work with that.